# Saving image over open file, A Generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: vb.net, image, gdi

I'm having trouble with my code, I'm trying to make a simple captcha for my program. The first time I run the sub it works fine, I'm guessing because the file is not "open" in my program. The second time I get the GDI+ error. I'm pretty sure this is an issue with the bitmaps being locked the 2nd time around, I'm just a little stuck.

```vb
Sub generatePasswordImage(password As String)

        'This is the image where we are going to write the text on it.
        Dim stringMasterImageName As String = Application.StartupPath + "\MasterImage.jpg"
        Dim bitmapImage As Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(stringMasterImageName)

        Dim bitmapMasterImage As Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bitmapImage, New Size(400, 150))
        Dim graphicsMasterImage As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapMasterImage)

        'Set the alignment based on the coordinates 
        Dim stringformatWriteTextFormat As StringFormat = New StringFormat()
        stringformatWriteTextFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

        'Do some rotation effects
        Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
        Dim rotation As Integer = Generator.Next(-10, 5)

        graphicsMasterImage.RotateTransform(rotation)

        Dim centerImgWidth As Integer = Generator.Next(CInt(graphicsMasterImage.VisibleClipBounds.Size.Width / 3), CInt(graphicsMasterImage.VisibleClipBounds.Size.Width / 2))
        Dim centerImgHiehgt As Integer = Generator.Next(CInt(graphicsMasterImage.VisibleClipBounds.Size.Height / 3), CInt(graphicsMasterImage.VisibleClipBounds.Size.Height / 2))

        'Set the font color
        Dim colorStringColor As Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black
        graphicsMasterImage.DrawString(password, New Font("Tahoma", 14, FontStyle.Bold), _
                                       New SolidBrush(colorStringColor), New Point(centerImgWidth, centerImgHiehgt), stringformatWriteTextFormat)

        Dim stringOutPutFileName As String = Application.StartupPath + "\Pass.jpg"
        bitmapMasterImage.Save(stringOutPutFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        bitmapMasterImage.Dispose()
        bitmapImage.Dispose()

    End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27640311/1070452  It almost always means you have an image open on the file or basic access problems. `Application.StartupPath` may be problematic if that is `Program Files...`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, ill take a look at that link. It appears that the bitmap is still locked after the first save for some reason.

Comment: if the previous image is shown somewhere (or you just have an image open on it) you cant save to the same file name