# VB.NET A generic error occurred in GDI+ when Bitmap.Save()

Tags: vb.net

I'm now created an application that encode value into QR code, and turn into image. Then, I want to store the image to my local. But, I tried many solutions that I found on Google and here. The issue still prompt out unexpectedly everytime. My code and a sample error picture is shown below. Please help me!
[A generic error occured in GDI+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXNgI.png)

```
    Dim qrCodeObject As QRCodeEncoder = New QRCodeEncoder()
    Dim image As Image
    Dim bitmap As Bitmap

    qrCodeObject.QRCodeEncodeMode = QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.BYTE
    qrCodeObject.QRCodeScale = 6
    qrCodeObject.QRCodeVersion = 5
    qrCodeObject.QRCodeErrorCorrect = QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.H

    image = qrCodeObject.Encode(value)
    bitmap = New Bitmap(image)
    bitmap.Save(value + ".jpg")
```

ANSWER: Always save file with different name and doesn't include any illegal characters

Comment: what is "value" when it happens?

Comment: You should us `&` to concat strings. If you have Option Strict On this is safer.

Comment: String concatenation with `+` in VB is prone to error. Use `&`, or better yet `Path.Combine()` to build filenames. @MattWilko beat me to it.

Comment: @Jens noted for that. Thanks

Comment: You get this exception whenever it fails to write the file.  Many possible reasons.  Get a much better diagnostic with `File.WriteAllText(value + ".jpg", "")`.  And do keep in mind that you are not actually writing a JPEG file, it is PNG unless you use the overload that takes the *ImageFormat* argument.  And you *must* add `bitmap.Dispose()`, failure to do so will keep a lock on the file that makes the next Save() call fail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing "Generic error occurred in GDI+" while generating a Barcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308234/fixing-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-while-generating-a-barcode)

Answer (score 0):

Path concatenation with simple strings is crap.
Use `Path.Combine` to build a path, because this ensures your path does
contain needed slashes if it would otherwise not be valid.

```
Dim Pat As String = Path.Combine(String.Concat(value, ".jpg"))

bitmap.save(Pat)
```

If this does not help, we need to know what "value" contains in your case.

Comment: `Path.Combine` does not repair/filter or fix illegal characters.  Test your code using value = `"foo:bar?"` the result is still illegal

Comment: Actually my value normally will replace with hash value of an ID

Comment: Plutonix I'm sorry, you are right. Path.Combine does not repair/filter or fix illegal characters.
I have had seen a self written method that had this functionality.

IvanTuang could you 
post what you get when you write:

Dim Pat As String = Path.Combine(String.Concat(value, ".jpg"))

Throw New Exception(Pat)

?

Comment: @IvanTuang then you are almost certainly trying to save to an illegal filename.  Use something else.  Path.Combine *will* do things like ignore segments 0 and 1 if segment 2 starts with a drive designation

Comment: Furthermore @SiriSch you are defeating the entire purpose of `Path.Combine` by using `String.Concat`, as this will just mash the two strings together again without regard for anything. It's just like using `value & ".jpg"` in the first place.

Comment: @Plutonix I think you're correct. Because I'm using hash value as the file name to store the image. After I changed, it's looks fine now! Thank you everyone

Comment: Jens you are wrong because the Threadcreator wants to create a file. In this case the String.Concat within Path.Combine is legitim.

Try this code:

        Dim filename As String = "hello"
        Dim Pat As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), filename, ".jpg")


This is shit.

There you have to do:
Dim Pat As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), String.Concat(filename, ".jpg"))

Otherwise I would say it is right to use Path.Combine without String.Concat if you want to combine directories.

Comment: You are right about the extension, my bad. The `Path.Combine` serves no purpose though in your example, as it just returns the input when called with 1 parameter.